# Dialog panels do not hide properly on switch - is there a workaround?

Tags: dialog, panel, dm-script

I have a dialog that contains two panels as shown below, created with the given code. As one can see in the right image, the second panel still contains content from the first panel.

[image: Dialog panels]

**Is there any workaround to fix that?**

I feel like bugs like these should be mentionend on Stackoverflow.

```c
class TestDialog : UIFrame{
    TagGroup panel_list;
    
    /**
     * Switch to the `index`-th panel.
     */
    void switchToPanel(object self, number index){
        panel_list.DLGValue(index);
    }
    
    void switchToPanel0(object self){self.switchToPanel(0);}
    void switchToPanel1(object self){self.switchToPanel(1);}
    
    /**
     * Create the dialog content
     */
    TagGroup createContent(object self){
        panel_list = DLGCreatePanelList(0);
        
        TagGroup box, switch_button, input, panel;

        // panel 1
        box = DLGCreateBox("Panel 1");
        
        // switch panel button
        switch_button = DLGCreatePushButton("Switch to panel 2", "switchToPanel1");
        box.DLGAddElement(switch_button);
        
        // input field
        input = DLGCreateStringField("ABC");
        box.DLGAddElement(input);
        
        panel = DLGCreatePanel();
        panel.DLGAddElement(box);
        panel_list.DLGAddElement(panel);

        // panel 2
        box = DLGCreateBox("Panel 2");
        
        // switch panel button
        switch_button = DLGCreatePushButton("Switch to panel 1", "switchToPanel0");
        box.DLGAddElement(switch_button);
        
        // add a label so both boxes have different heights
        box.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel(""));
        
        // input field
        input = DLGCreateStringField("DEF");
        box.DLGAddElement(input);
        
        panel = DLGCreatePanel();
        panel.DLGAddElement(box);
        panel_list.DLGAddElement(panel);
        
        TagGroup wrapper = DLGCreateGroup();
        wrapper.DLGAddElement(panel_list);

        return wrapper;
    }

    object init(object self){
        return self.super.init(self.createContent())
    }
}

alloc(TestDialog).init().pose()
```

---

Comment: I have not (yet) looked at the actual question, but if you believe to have found a proper **bug** of DigitalMicrograph, please report it at [Gatan's software site](https://www.gatan.com/resources/software) using the form ["Issue and Bug Reporting"](http://swbugs.gatan.com/loginsolosubmit.htm) It is still okay to ask for a workaround solution here on site, though.

Comment: General note: If you declare an object variable on the root-level of a DM-script, it will remain in scope after the script ends. You might want to either enclose the main-script with a `{` `}` or write it without a declared object variable as `alloc(TestDialog).Init().pose();` - This is one of DM-scripts peculiarities.

Comment: I don't know why I thought this is due to Line 35 and 54. I was 100% sure that testing it without those lines everything would work. But it doesn't. I tested my example again and I can confirm that this has nothing to do with those lines. I updated my question.

Comment: If you don't mind, I've edited all of the cross-out text completely away. Makes it easier for the next person reading this (for the first time). If you disagree, just roll back.

Comment: I had a bit of a go but couldn't find a workaround. Seems to be a proper bug of GMS 3 though. (Code works fine with GMS 2)

Comment: @BmyGuest I maybe found a solution. But after that lines 35 and 54 I don't trust my own tests anymore :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fix: Hide manually

After a lot of trying out I think triggering the `UIFrame::SetElementIsShown()` manually fixes this issue. In the given example one can add the identifiers `input0` to the first and `input1` to the second input and then change the `TestDialog::switchToPanel()` function to the following:

```c
/**
* Switch to the `index`-th panel.
*/
void switchToPanel(object self, number index){
    panel_list.DLGValue(index);
    
    if(index == 0){
        self.setElementIsShown("input0", 1);
        self.setElementIsShown("input1", 0);
    }
    else{
        self.setElementIsShown("input0", 0);
        self.setElementIsShown("input1", 1);
    }
}
```

The complete code is then:

```c
class TestDialog : UIFrame{
    TagGroup panel_list;
    
    /**
    * Switch to the `index`-th panel.
    */
    void switchToPanel(object self, number index){
        panel_list.DLGValue(index);
        
        if(index == 0){
            self.setElementIsShown("input0", 1);
            self.setElementIsShown("input1", 0);
        }
        else{
            self.setElementIsShown("input0", 0);
            self.setElementIsShown("input1", 1);
        }
    }
    
    void switchToPanel0(object self){self.switchToPanel(0);}
    void switchToPanel1(object self){self.switchToPanel(1);}
    
    /**
     * Create the dialog content
     */
    TagGroup createContent(object self){
        panel_list = DLGCreatePanelList(0);
        
        TagGroup box, switch_button, input, panel;

        // panel 1
        box = DLGCreateBox("Panel 1");
        
        // switch panel button
        switch_button = DLGCreatePushButton("Switch to panel 2", "switchToPanel1");
        box.DLGAddElement(switch_button);
        
        // input field
        input = DLGCreateStringField("ABC");
        input.DLGIdentifier("input0");
        box.DLGAddElement(input);
        
        panel = DLGCreatePanel();
        panel.DLGAddElement(box);
        panel_list.DLGAddElement(panel);

        // panel 2
        box = DLGCreateBox("Panel 2");
        
        // switch panel button
        switch_button = DLGCreatePushButton("Switch to panel 1", "switchToPanel0");
        box.DLGAddElement(switch_button);
        
        // add a label so both boxes have different heights
        box.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel(""));
        
        // input field
        input = DLGCreateStringField("DEF");
        input.DLGIdentifier("input1");
        box.DLGAddElement(input);
        
        panel = DLGCreatePanel();
        panel.DLGAddElement(box);
        panel_list.DLGAddElement(panel);
        
        TagGroup wrapper = DLGCreateGroup();
        wrapper.DLGAddElement(panel_list);

        return wrapper;
    }

    object init(object self){
        return self.super.init(self.createContent())
    }
}

alloc(TestDialog).init().pose()
```

## Workaround: Use Tabs

I also found out that tabs work with the exact same code. So if possible one can just replace the panels with tabs.

```c
class TestDialog : UIFrame{
    TagGroup tab_list;
    TagGroup inputs;
    
    /**
     * Create the dialog content
     */
    TagGroup createContent(object self){
        inputs = NewTagList();
        tab_list = DLGCreateTabList(0);
        
        TagGroup box, input, tab;

        // panel 1
        box = DLGCreateBox("Panel 1");
        
        // input field
        input = DLGCreateStringField("ABC");
        box.DLGAddElement(input);
        // save the input field in a TagList, this creates the problem
        inputs.TagGroupInsertTagAsTagGroup(infinity(), input);
        
        tab = DLGCreateTab("Tab 1");
        tab.DLGAddElement(box);
        tab_list.DLGAddElement(tab);

        // panel 2
        box = DLGCreateBox("Panel 2");
        
        // add a label so both boxes have different heights
        box.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel(""));
        
        // input field
        input = DLGCreateStringField("DEF");
        box.DLGAddElement(input);
        inputs.TagGroupInsertTagAsTagGroup(infinity(), input);
        
        tab = DLGCreateTab("Tab 2");
        tab.DLGAddElement(box);
        tab_list.DLGAddElement(tab);
        
        TagGroup wrapper = DLGCreateGroup();
        wrapper.DLGAddElement(tab_list);

        return wrapper;
    }

    object init(object self){
        return self.super.init(self.createContent())
    }
}

object dialog = alloc(TestDialog).Init();
dialog.pose();
```

Comment: +1 for the tabs solution. The "fix", however, still does not give me a clean display of the panels unfortunately.

Comment: @BmyGuest I forgot to mention one has to add the identifiers `input0` and `input1` to the inputs. I posted the complete code. Does that work for you? If not I will remove the "Fix".

Comment: @BmyGuest Do you think I should report that as a bug? That panels, boxes and inputs do not work together? I tried leaving out one of them and then it seems to work. Only this combination seems to be the problem. But I didn't spend too much time on that.

Comment: Yes, the fix now works. Interesting that you've to hide/show the field item. I figured that I'd need the Identifier myself, but added it to the panel or box item (which did not work). And yes, as your initial script works on GMS 2 but not on GMS 3 and doesn't contain an obvious scripting mistake, I would report it as a bug. Best just as "Dialog display bug - panel switch leaves ghost trace" or such with your example script as way to easily reproduce.

Comment: Ok, I sent a bug report. Thank your for your help